Why does this expression for an orthogonal projector work?
With the normal matrix $F$, I am asked to find the orthogonal projectors onto each of its subspaces. In my class notes I found out the following reasoning: $$P_i \mathbf{u}_i=\alpha \mathbf{u}_i$$ which I get because of the characteristics of the projections. What I do not understand is the following statememt: $$P_i=\frac{\mathbf{u}_i \mathbf{u}_i^\dagger}{\mathbf{u}_i^\dagger · \mathbf{u}_i}$$

What happens if you multiply that matrix times $\mathbf{u}_i$?

@Leo if you are talking about matrix F, you get $\alpha \mathbf{u}_i$, right?

Yes. But have you tried to operate using the right hand side? What is $\mathbf{u}_i^\dagger$ multiplied by $\mathbf{u}_i$?

It is the dot product, it is a scalar

I found a similar question with an answer that actually works with my doubt
